# display image on click from datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql

how can i display an image that i already stored in the database to appear on a picturebox when i click on it on the datagridview... i'm still quite new to coding c# so i don't really know how to do this

> private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>           {

```
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            string ItemID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            string ItemName = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
            string SupplierID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
            string Quantity = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
            string Price = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            textBox1.Text = ItemID;
            textBox2.Text = ItemName;
            textBox3.Text = SupplierID;
            textBox4.Text = Quantity;
            textBox5.Text = Price;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you access Cell[1] where you already pull out the ItemName??? Also: What datatype does the (correct) cell have? Is it an Imagecolumn? Then you could simply use its FormattedValue and assign it to the pbx.Image.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to use [PictureBox.Refresh()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx). After setup image use refresh method, for example:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but its still the same @Art